What is a good way to store API keys on an Express server? What would that request look like?
I know that you shouldn't save API secrets in the frontend, even in a .env file. When building, it gets stored and malicious scripts can access it. I read this Stack Overflow article, and I don't want to use a secret manager. I am running a backend Express application. How would I keep my secrets on there instead?

At some point the secrets have to be somewhere. Either that's on a filesystem, some configuration panel or an extrernal secrets manager. If you manually start your express servers on some VPS, your best option is probably still environment variables. And this is not the end of the world. Just make sure they stay on the server and never get committed to git and in the hands of others.

But if you want it to be secure you know the answer, it's a secrets manager / secure parameter store.

You can store in Pipeline
